# Build a C# project fails in nuget restore package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

Tags: nuget, travis-ci, nuget-package-restore

I have this [Azure Notification Hubs Sample](https://github.com/saramgsilva/NotificationHubs/tree/dc6581d965d6fc4a93f9922185a53e4ccfae2d52)

and it fails because

> The 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 0.12.0-build17386' package requires
>   NuGet client version '2.8.50313' or above, but the current NuGet
>   version is '2.8.1.0'. The command "eval nuget restore
>   src/NotificationHubSample.sln" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package. In its .nuspec file it has the following:

```
<metadata minClientVersion="2.8.50313">
```

NuGet will check the minClientVersion defined by a NuGet package against its product version to see if they are compatible.

The minClientVersion used in the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package seems to be using the NuGet assembly file version and not the NuGet product version. So NuGet restore or install will always fail, at least until a newer version of NuGet is released. The latest NuGet released has a product version of 2.8.3.

Note that I am ignoring NuGet 3.0 which currently has a CTP release. So this NuGet package would work with NuGet 3.0 so maybe the creators of the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package have only tested it with that version.

So your options are:

1. Report the problem to the owners of the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package and wait for them to fix it.
2. Use NuGet.exe 3.0 to run the package restore with Travis.
3. Use a different version of the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package which does not have this minClientVersion restriction.

Comment: thanks for the response, I was looking to the project and I removed it because I am not using it.